# Fetching Firebase data for a functional expandable React Native calendar: What am I missing?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am unsure of how i can implement link the data that is being stored in firebase and create an expandable calendar to list the tasks for each day. The demo code given has their own agendaItems is there a foundation code i can use to work on?

```
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, DatePickerIOS } from 'react-native';
import { ExpandableCalendar, AgendaList, CalendarProvider, WeekCalendar } from 'react-native-calendars';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs, addDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

// const timeToString = (time) => {
//   const date = new Date(time);
//   return date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
// };

const timeToString = (time) => {
  const date = new Date(time);
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
};


const theme = {
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  calendarBackground: '#ffffff',
  textSectionTitleColor: '#b6c1cd',
  selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#478C5C',
  selectedDayTextColor: '#ffffff',
  todayTextColor: '#478C5C',
  dayTextColor: '#2d4150',
  textDisabledColor: '#999999',
  arrowColor: '#478C5C',
};

const firebaseConfig = {
  -
};

const CalendarScreen = (props) => {
  const { weekView } = props;
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const theme = useRef(getTheme());

  const fetchTasks = async () => {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getFirestore(app);
    const tasksSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'tasks'));
    const tasksData = tasksSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    setItems(tasksData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTasks();
  }, []);

  const renderItem = useCallback(({ item }) => {
    return <AgendaItem item={item} />;
  }, []);

  return (
    <CalendarProvider
      date={new Date()} // Set the initial date here
    >
      {weekView ? (
        <WeekCalendar firstDay={1} />
      ) : (
        <ExpandableCalendar
          initialPosition={ExpandableCalendar.positions.CLOSED}
          markedDates={{}}
          leftArrowImageSource={leftArrowIcon}
          rightArrowImageSource={rightArrowIcon}
          theme={theme.current}
        />
      )}
      <AgendaList
        sections={items}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </CalendarProvider>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff', // Set the background color to white
  },
  headerContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  subtitleText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginLeft: 8,
    color: 'gray',
  },
  taskInputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  taskInput: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: '#cccccc',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginRight: 8,
  },
  addButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#478C5C',
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  addButtonLabel: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  dayContainer: {
    width: 36,
    height: 36,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: '#478C5C',
  },
});


export default CalendarScreen;
```

currently im doing this but it keep giving me an error
import typeof DatePickerIOS from './Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS';

Comment: What is different between the code you posted and what you want?